# Tkinter chlid / parrent window management

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have trouble making tkinter behaviour to meet the all of the conditions below when creating child window from action on the parent window:

- focus on child window
- disable interaction with parent window content
- enable user to close parent window with default exit button in right upper corner of parent window (that action should also close child window)

I have tried `child.transient(root)` and `child.grab_set()` but none of them work as I would like it to.

```
from tkinter.ttk import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry("200x200")
 

def openNewWindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel(master)
    newWindow.geometry("200x200")
    Label(newWindow,
          text ="This is a new window").pack()
    newWindow.grab_set()
 
 
label = Label(master,
              text ="This is the main window")
label.pack(pady = 10)

btn = Button(master,
             text ="Click to open a new window",
             command = openNewWindow)
btn.pack(pady = 10)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you've tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, using `grab_set` seems to do exactly what you want. It should work the same on all platforms, though I don't have the ability to test it on any other platforms.

In the following example you can click a button on the main window to create a new window. When that new window is open, you cannot click the button in the main window again. You're still able to close the main window with the close button on the title bar.

```
import tkinter as tk

def new_window():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    entry = tk.Entry(top)
    entry.pack(fill="x", padx=20, pady=20)
    entry.focus_set()
    top.grab_set()

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="new window", command=new_window)
button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's interesting. I am on Windows 10 and as long as child window is opened I cannot use exit button on parent window.

Comment: @Loiczeq: then this must be a feature of Windows. Tkinter really doesn't have much control over the window decorations - those are supplied by the OS.

Comment: Works as described on Ubuntu Linux.